# Save chromium browser's session

Tags: chromium, browser, session

How can I manually save the session in chromium-broswer?

I have a Notebook with damaged battery *(only gives 5~6 minutes of backup, planning to buy a new one)*, and in our country power outages ("Load Shedding") are quite common.

So, I have had to close my session before shutting down my laptop. When I re-open chromium, there is no tab with previous session.

The question is: **How can I manually save my session before closing the laptop?**

Comment: to have more control on sessions, use some session manager. I find "Session Buddy" useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the chromium window open :

Click on the wench icon on the right of your toolbar. Click **Settings** -> On **Basics** Section, in the option under **On startup** heading, Choose the radio button with **Reopen the pages that were open last**.

Now, Your session will be always be saved.

See the image below:

[image: Chromium settings image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Session Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bbcnbpafconjjigibnhbfmmgdbbkcjfi) extension. It's awesome -- I use it regularly. :D